# undefined method `output_data' for #<EventManager:0x007fa4220320c8> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, class, methods, nomethoderror

I keep getting this error:

> `event_manager.rb:83:in`': undefined method `output_data' for #<EventManager:0x007fc5018320c0> (NoMethodError)`

I am following the exercise [on this website](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/eventmanager.html#iteration-3%3a-outputting-cleaned-data):

Here is my code (My error comes towards the end with `DEF OUTPUT_DATA` ...):

```
# Dependencies

require "csv"

# Class Definition

class EventManager

INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER = "0000000000"
INVALID_ZIPCODE = "00000"

def initialize
puts "EventManager Initialized."
filename = "event_attendees.csv"
@file = CSV.open(filename, {:headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol})
end

def print_names
@file.each do |line|
  puts line.inspect
  puts line[2] + " " + line[3]
 end
end

#printing home phone number method
def print_numbers
 @file.each do |line|
  number = clean_number(line[:homephone])
  puts number
end
end
 #cleaning numbers method
def clean_number(number)
  cleaner= number.delete('.' + ')' + '(' + '-')
  if cleaner.length == 10
    # Do Nothing
  elsif cleaner.length == 11
   if cleaner.start_with?("1")
    cleaner = cleaner[1..-1]
  else
    cleaner = INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER
  end
else
  cleaner = INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER
end
  return cleaner
end

def clean_zipcode(original)
    if original.nil?
    zipcode = INVALID_ZIPCODE
  elsif original.length < 5
    while original.length < 5
      original = original.insert(0, "0")
    end  
  else
  return original
end
return zipcode
end


def print_zipcodes
  @file.each do |line|
    zipcode = clean_zipcode(line[:zipcode])
    puts zipcode
end

def output_data
output = CSV.open("event_attendees_clean.csv", "w")
@file.each do |line|
  output << line
end
end
end
end





# Script
manager = EventManager.new
#manager.print_numbers
#manager.print_zipcodes
manager.output_data
```

I've tried several things, checked all through the internet and I just can't figure it out myself.

I will really appreciate *any* help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @David , I am new at posting here, and I see you made some corrections to my original post. I just wonder why are they necessary? I mean, what is it that was not right enough ? Thanks!

Comment: It was just a few cosmetic changes. Like capitalization of words and putting code inside a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You have definition of `output_data` method embedded in `print_zipcodes` (iteration block is not closed). Try indenting your code -- mistake is very easy to spot then.

Comment: thanks @samuil !! you don't know how long i have been stuck on this

Comment: If answer solved your problem consider accepting it, so other users can easily find known solutions.